# Locating the path of pdflatex compiler using wxExecute() of wxWidgets in C++

Tags: c++, macos, path, wxwidgets, pdflatex

I need to find the path of pdflatex compiler in system from within a C++ application. For this purpose, I wrote this piece of code:

```
const wxString cmd = wxT("which pdflatex");

wxArrayString output, errors;
int code = wxExecute(cmd, output, errors);

for(int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
  wxLogMessage( wxT("output string = ") + output[i]);
}
```

The issue is that this code renders the desired output when the command (cmd) is "which java" , "which gcc" etc. But, with "which pdflatex", it renders a null output. Although, pdflatex is located in the system and "which pdflatex" renders the correct output path when run directly on the terminal.

P.S. I am using Mac OSX, incase that could be any issue.

Comment: Have you checked the return code or the errors in the wxArrayString?

Comment: @SteveL I checked. wxArrayString for errors is empty, i.e., no errors are being generated.